# Array container is not enough to hold all needed values

Tags: java, arrays

this program finds fibonacci sequence starting at 1 then separate the 2 digit numbers so that it's not too big then factorial the numbers and add them.
my problem is that its missing the final value in the sequence because the array is not big enough, but if I change it it's giving me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error (Exception)

```
 int sum = 1;
    int input;

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    input = console.nextInt();

    int[] fib = new int[input];
    int[] out = new int[input];
    int[] fib2 = new int[input];

    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;

    fib2[0] = 0;
    fib2[1] = 1;
    if (input > 0) {

        if (input <= 7) { // for numbers 1,1,2,3,5,8 
            for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {
                fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
                out[i] = factorial(fib[i]);

            }
        } else { // this is for the 2 digit numbers 13,21,34,55,89
            for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {
                fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
                fib2[i] = fib2[i - 1] + fib2[i - 2];
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {
                fib[i] = separate(fib[i]);
                fib2[i] = separate2(fib2[i]);
                out[i] = factorial(fib[i]) + factorial(fib2[i]);
            }

        }

        for (int i : out) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
}
```

output is 40,490 but it should be 40,730
all is working except that if I input 10 it's missing the final value 55.
computation is like this 1!+1!+2!+3!+5!+8!+1!+3!+2!+1!+3!+4!+5!+5! = 40,730

Comment: Why is the length of `out` array 20 and not `input` (as the other arrays)?

Comment: At first I thought that it's not holding enough value so i change it to 20 because it doesn't matter it will just add zero's

Comment: If input might be > 20, `out[i]` in your final loop will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ArrayList` instead of `Array` when you don't know exactly how many data your `array` will store.

`ArrayList` is slightly different from `Array`

You can learn more about `ArrayList` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-in-java/).

Replace your given code with my code:-

```
int sum = 1;
int input;

System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
input = console.nextInt();

ArrayList<Integer> fib = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> fib2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

fib.add(0);
fib.add(1);

fib2.add(0);
fib2.add(1);
if (input > 0) {

    if (input <= 7) { // for numbers 1,1,2,3,5,8 
        for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {
            fib.add(i, fib.get(i - 1) + fib.get(i - 2));
            out.add(i, factorial(fib.get(i)));

        }
    } else { // this is for the 2 digit numbers 13,21,34,55,89
        for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {
            fib.add(i, fib.get(i - 1) + fib.get(i - 2));
            fib2.add(i, fib2.get(i - 1) + fib2.get(i - 2));
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {
            fib.add(i, separate(fib.get(i)));
            fib2.add(i, separate2(fib2.get(i)));
            out.add(i, factorial(fib.get(i)) + factorial(fib2.get(i)));
        }

    }

    for (int i : out) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```